# Python: Changing Elements in List

Tags: python, for-loop, element, variable-assignment

I have been observing this strange behaviour for a while. Now I would like to know the reason.

See the example below.

Can someone explain why - and whether there are other options more similar to the first version that do what the second does.

```
>>> a
>>> [1, 0, 1, 1]

>>> for el in a:
        el = 1

>>> a
>>> [1, 0, 1, 1]

>>> for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = 1

>>> a
>>> [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first snippet:

```
for el in a:
```

Gets only the values of the items in `a`, they're not references to the items *in* the list. So when you try to reassign it, you only change the value of `el`, not the item in your list.

While this:

```
a[i]
```

Retrieves the items of `a` themselves, not just the values.

To change all the values of `a`, you can create a new copy and reassign it back to `a`:

```
a = [1 for _ in a]
```

This is the most effective way. If you want to have both the value, and the index to reassign it, use `enumerate`:

```
for index, el in enumerate(a):
    print el #print the current value
    a[index] = 1 #change it,
    print el #and print the new one!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well that was a quick response! Thanks, did not know that.

Comment: Well, `el` *is* a reference to the item itself. But no it's not a reference to the position in the list, which I guess is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I generally end up using something like this:

```
a = [1 for el in a]
```

List comprehension is my preferred way of updating items in a list avoiding indices.

Answer (score 0):

Pythons variables are names for objects, not names for positions in memory. Hence

```
el = 1
```

Does not change the object `el` is pointing to to be `1`. Instead it make `el` now point to the object `1`. It does not modify anything in the list at all. For that you have to modify the list directly:

```
a[2] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

fast enumeration gives a immutable copy of the element thus the speed advantage over the index iteration method.

```
for el in a:# el is immutable
```

where as

```
for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = 1
```

modifies the value at its memory location as `listname[<index>]` is actually `baseaddress+index*offset`.  one of the reasons why index start with zero